# how do you create linear line on geom_bar in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to create stacked ggplot bar plot given this data set with linear line drawn:

```
        dput(t)
structure(list(Date = structure(c(16436, 16436, 16436, 16467, 
16467, 16467, 16467, 16467, 16679, 16679, 16679, 16679, 16679
), class = "Date"), Applicatio = structure(c(4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("DB", "Opt", 
"Tom", "Web"), class = "factor"), Code = structure(c(1L, 2L, 
4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("ch", 
"db", "tt", "zz"), class = "factor"), m = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("2015-01", 
"2015-02", "2015-09"), class = "factor"), count = c(1L, 3L, 1L, 
4L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 7L, 9L), Total = c(1L, 12L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 20L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 50L, 3L, 6L)), .Names = c("Date", 
"Applicatio", "Code", "m", "count", "Total"), row.names = c(NA, 
-13L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am trying this:

```
ggplot(subset(t, Date> as.Date(c("2015-01-01", format="%Y-%m-%d"))), aes(m,fill=Code))+geom_bar()+
  geom_smooth(aes(m,Total),method="lm", se=FALSE)+
        guides(colour=FALSE)
```

Comment: Did you get a warning message? What did it say?

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve, but it looks like you want this:

```
ggplot(subset(t, Date > as.Date("2015-01-01", format="%Y-%m-%d")), aes(m,fill=Code))+geom_bar()+
  geom_smooth(aes(m,Total,group=1),method="lm", se=FALSE)+
  guides(colour=FALSE)
```

Basically, you had a `c` function in the `subset` function that was not needed and then you needed to use `group=1` inside the `geom_smooth` function as mentioned by the warning.

[image]

So, yeah you can have a linear line on `geom_bar`.